# condition on map field in apex class

Tags: apex

I am working on apex class which will fetch details from Campaign Member object, once it is fetched I am looking at map size, if it is greater than zero then I am creating a record in Staging_Event_Attendee__c object.

in Campaign Member if ContactId field is not null then I am populating

```
Staging_Event_Attendee__c.Attendant = ContactId
```

now same like that if LeadId is not null then I need to populate

```
Staging_Event_Attendee__c.Lead__c = LeadId
```

Can anyone help me out in this issue, on Campaign Member record I can have either leadId or ContactId at time.

I need to have a condition to check whether LeadId or ContactId is not null, if leadId is not null then I need to create a new record where

```
Staging_Event_Attendee__c.Lead__c = CampaignMap.get(Con.Barcode__c).LeadId
```

If ContactId is not null then I need to create a new record where

```
Staging_Event_Attendee__c.Lead__c = CampaignMap.get(Con.Barcode__c).ContactId
```

Code is:

```
Map<Id,CampaignMember> CampaignMap = new Map<Id,CampaignMember>([select ContactId,LeadId,CampaignId from CampaignMember where Id in: barcodeSet]);
    for(Staging_Event_Attendee__c con : stagingEventAttendeeList) {
        if(CampaignMap.size()>0 ){
            if(CampaignMap.get(con.Barcode__c).LeadId != null) {
                con.Lead__c = CampaignMap.get(con.Barcode__c).LeadId;
            }else{
                con.Attendant__c = CampaignMap.get(con.Barcode__c).ContactId;
            }
            con.Campaign_ID__c = CampaignMap.get(con.Barcode__c).CampaignId;
            con.Date_Attended__c = system.now();
        }
        else{
            con.Invalid_Barcode__c = true;
            con.Date_Attended__c = system.now();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What issue you are facing here?

Comment: @वरुण, I updated my code but no fields are getting populated from Campaign Member to Staging Event Attendee record

Comment: Did you check that values are getting populated in `con` in the code?
And
Are you calling `update` on `stagingEventAttendeeList`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ma able to achieve it anyways

```
Map<Id,CampaignMember> CampaignMap = new Map<Id,CampaignMember>([select ContactId,LeadId,CampaignId from CampaignMember where Id in: barcodeSet]);
    for(Staging_Event_Attendee__c con : stagingEventAttendeeList) {
        if(CampaignMap.size()>0 ){
            if(CampaignMap.get(con.Barcode__c).LeadId != null) {
                con.Lead__c = CampaignMap.get(con.Barcode__c).LeadId;
            }else{
                con.Attendant__c = CampaignMap.get(con.Barcode__c).ContactId;
            }
            con.Campaign_ID__c = CampaignMap.get(con.Barcode__c).CampaignId;
            con.Date_Attended__c = system.now();
        }
        else{
            con.Invalid_Barcode__c = true;
            con.Date_Attended__c = system.now();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It may be important to note that if a lead converts into a contact while in the campaign, then depending on your conversion process a campaign member may have both LeadId and ContactId fields populated. In that circumstance you may want to prefer recording the Contact in your Staging_Event_Attendee__c record, but your if/else structure is giving preference to the Lead.